# MS SQL Server : update with less amount of rows in source table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

What is the best way to update `Table1` with all values from `Table2` if `Table2` has less rows than `Table1`? This considering that `Table2` has no key that can be joined to `Table1` for update.

```
TABLE1      TABLE2  RESULT TABLE1
id value    value   id value
----------------------------------------------------
1  NULL     4       1  4
2  NULL     6       2  6
3  NULL     8       3  8
4  NULL             4  4
5  NULL             5  6
6  NULL             6  8
7  NULL             7  4
```

Hope I make sense.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Pardon, did not specify its Microsoft SQL Server 2012. :/

EXAMPLE for SOLUTION:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(id int, avalue int)
DECLARE @t2 TABLE(id INT, avalue int)

-- Generate 20 rows in @t1 table
INSERT 
INTO    @t1 (id)
SELECT  Number
FROM    dbo.Numbers 
WHERE   Number BETWEEN 1 AND 20

-- Generate 5 rows and value @t2 table
INSERT 
INTO    @t2 (id,avalue)
SELECT  Number,
        Number
FROM    dbo.Numbers 
WHERE   Number BETWEEN 1 AND 5

-- The goal is to take all rows from @t2
-- and repeatively insert them in order into @t1

UPDATE  t1
SET     t1.avalue = t2.avalue
FROM    @t1 t1 
JOIN    (   SELECT t2.*, COUNT(*) OVER () AS cnt
            FROM @t2 t2
        )   AS t2
ON      (t1.id - 1) % t2.cnt = t2.id - 1;

SELECT  *
FROM    @t1
```

Comment: _"Hope I make sense"_ not really.

Comment: Darn, perhaps I should improve question then. :/

Comment: It makes sense - he wants to populate the `value` column in the first table with the `value` columns in the second table in order, over and over.  E.g.: 4, 6, 8, 4, 6, 8, etc.

Comment: Yes, bad example. Table2 has id aswell, 1-3.

Comment: @marc_s That's just an opinion. Besides it's not relevant here. There problem is there is no relation between the two tables. Siyual seems to be spot on in his understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting problem.  This first solution is for MySQL (I originally read the question as being about that database).  After this solution is the one for SQL Server.

You need to generate a `join` key.  Let me assume that `id` is really sequential.  Then you can use modulo arithmetic to do the match:

```
update table1 t1
       (select (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum, value
        from table2 cross join
             (select @rn := -1) vars
       ) t2 cross join
       (select count(*) as cnt from table2) cnt
       on mod((t1.id - 1), cnt.cnt) = t2.seqnum
    set t1.value = t2.value;
```

If the id in `table1` is not sequential, you can use a variable for that as well.  It just further complicates the query:

```
update table1 t1 join
       (select @rn1 := @rn + 1) as seqnum, id
        from table1 t1 cross join
             (select @rn1 := 0) vars
        order by id
       ) t1s
       on t1.id =  t1s.id join
       (select (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum, value
        from table2 cross join
             (select @rn := -1) vars
       ) t2 cross join
       (select count(*) as cnt from table2) cnt
       on mod((t1s.seqnum - 1), cnt.cnt) = t2.seqnum
    set t1.value = t2.value;
```

EDIT:

You can readily do the same thing in SQL Server.  It is actually easier:

```
update table1 t1
    set t1.value = t2.value;
    from table1 t1 join
         (select t2.*, count(*) over () as cnt
          from table2 t2
         ) t2
         on (t1.id - 1) % t2.cnt = (t2.id - 1);
```

This formulation depends on the `id`s being sequential with no gaps.  It is easy enough to loosen this restriction, but the query gets a wee bit more complicated.

Comment: @mrw . . . I always forget if SQL Server uses `%` or `mod()`.  This is made worse because of this documentation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634767.aspx.  Components of the SQL Server system *do* use `mod()` and they are documented as if the database did as well.

Comment: Ah, explains it. :) Removed my earlier comment. The answer was perfect. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
DECLARE @Table1  AS TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    Value INT
)

DECLARE @Table2 AS  TABLE
(
    Value INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table1
SELECT 1, NULL UNION
SELECT 2, NULL UNION
SELECT 3, NULL UNION
SELECT 4, NULL UNION
SELECT 5, NULL UNION
SELECT 6, NULL UNION
SELECT 7, NULL 


INSERT INTO @Table2
SELECT 4 UNION
SELECT 6 UNION
SELECT 8 

DECLARE @nCOUNT as INT

SET @nCOUNT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Table2)

UPDATE TB1 SET TB1.Value = TB2.Value FROM @Table1 AS TB1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT T1.ID, T2.Value FROM 
(SELECT *, CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) % @nCOUNT) = 0
                THEN @nCOUNT
                ELSE (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) % @nCOUNT)
            END AS ROID
FROM @Table1) AS T1

LEFT JOIN (SELECT VALUE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Value) AS ID FROM @Table2) AS T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ROID) AS TB2
ON TB1.ID = TB2.ID

SELECT * FROM @Table1
```